# Filter question by pinned sites in the iOS widget

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, ios-app-today-view

Please could the iOS widget have some way of viewing (and perhaps filtering) the items only from my pinned sites?

I find that refresh feature of the widget is very useful.

Comment: Well, it currently shows HNQs so I'm not sure filtering that by your pinned sites makes sense (defeats the whole point of HNQs and what if there are none from your pinned sites?), so there would probably need to be different criteria for showing questions.

Comment: @Cai I would say it makes a lot of sense. I regularly find myself swiping past loads of questions that are of no interest to me. There will always be some hot network questions, as the term is relative. You just show the hottest ones from the pinned sites

Comment: My point is that filtering the HNQs list doesn't make sense, there certainly aren't questions from *all* sites in the list at all times. Taking the "hottest" questions from your pinned sites would be a different list.