# Customised hot questions for extension

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, ios-app-today-view

I love the hot questions extension I found upon upgrading to iOS 10, I would really like to be able to customise the questions that show up though, really what I would like to be able to see only really falls under swift (iOS), Physics, Mathematics, Music... you get the point. Even just being able to select which sites show up would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Filter question by pinned sites in the iOS widget](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286047/filter-question-by-pinned-sites-in-the-ios-widget)

Comment: [SOX](https://github.com/soscripted/sox) allows HNQ to be filtered by site.

Comment: This is very cool, but I use the app 99% of the time :/

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't that default the purpose of the HNQ list? It are the hot questions on the network, not a list of hot question for just a few sites.

I could agree it is useful sometimes to have a hot questions per site or tag, but that would be a totally different feature than the one you are requesting now.

Comment: I get what your saying, and maybe I'm missing the point of HNQ, but as far as I can tell it has two uses; discovering and engaging in questions you may not have searched for yourself across the platform (promoting the other sites) or giving hot questions a wider audience to find someone who could potentially give an excellent answer. I understand that, however there are certain areas I'm not knowledgable or interested in. This is not to say I want to massively restrict it, I just would like to avoid getting questions from say English Language Learners (nothing against that site).

Comment: But then your request goes much further than just the app. It is the basics of the HNQ list.

Comment: Couldn't you just filter the questions shown by site after retrieving the list in the code for the extension?